# Avoiding if else condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have two parameter, for example a,b. I have a situation like if both parameters(a,b) can have values or both may not have values or either of the one them have values.

Example:

1st Condition : a=10, b=20

2nd Condition:  a=None, b=20

3rd Condition: a=10 , b=None

4th Condition: a=None, b= None

I have to do some operation if value is present and log it. Currently i am doing like below,
Is there any efficient way to do this?

```
if not a:
    print "Value a not present"
if not b:
   print "Value b not present"

# Do operation for A
a = a+1 
# Do operation for B
b = b+1
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid conditions?

Comment: Is the idea to only increment `a` or `b` if it is not `None`? In that case, just add an `else` statement to each `if` statement where you increment it. Also, it might be better to check for `if a is None`, as `not a` will be `True` for `a = 0`.

Comment: If you just want to simplyfied maybe you can use:
if None in (a, b):
    print("value a or b not present")

Comment: i do not to avoid conditions. I want any better way to do other than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collapse everything into two lines:

```
a = a + 1 if (a is not None) else (a or print('a not present'))
b = b + 1 if (b is not None) else (b or print('b not present'))
```

If `a` or `b` are `None`, the `print`s are executed. Here's a demo:

```
In [692]: a, b = 10, None

In [693]: a = a + 1 if (a is not None) else (a or print('a not present'))
     ...: b = b + 1 if (b is not None) else (b or print('b not present'))
     ...: 
b not present

In [694]: a, b
Out[694]: (11, None)
```

---

At the end of the day, if you were to ask me what to use, I definitely wouldn't recommend the above. Compare this:

```
def check_and_increment(val):
    if val is None:
         return print('Not found!')

    return val + 1

a = check_and_increment(a)
b = check_and_increment(b)
```

To my answer above. Which is more readable?

Comment: what if either of the initial values are 0? They won't be incremented, whereas they would in OP's example.

Comment: @khelwood Totally not. I'd say "stick to your multiline if-else", but this answer could be considered for research purposes.. :p

Comment: I think it's worth saying that in your answer.

Comment: @khelwood Sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `args` instead, if the logic for all the params is going to be same?

```
def func(*args):
    args = [value + 1 if value else value for value in args]
```

Otherwise, you can reduce the number of conditionals, but you have to use at least one.